# How to change the Queue Id in WX2?

Tags: kognitio-wx2, kognitio, wx2

Following is the current records from the QUEUES.

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.IPE_ALLQUEUES;

ID      NAME
------- ----------
100004  NAGIOS
1       DEFAULT
100003  OTHER
100002  APP
100001  ANALYST
0       NONQUEUED
```

ID column is currently defined as INTEGER and we are planning to change this as SMALLINT. So I need to change the id's as follows

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.IPE_ALLQUEUES;

ID      NAME
------- ----------
14      NAGIOS
1       DEFAULT
13      OTHER
12      APP
11      ANALYST
0       NONQUEUED
```

How can this be acheived in WX2?

**Note**: I am not asking about a simple update on the ids since this is a configuration meta data table for the WX2 engine. This is a bit intricate.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to specify the ids used in IPE_ALL_QUEUES, but why do you need them to be SMALLINTs? Is it because you are storing a very large number of references to this table elsewhere? If so, you could add a layer of indirection which maps the SMALLINT (e.g. 14) to the required INT (e.g. 100004) - the indirection table would be replicated and tiny, and the cost of joining using it in adding to IPE_ALL_QEUEUES and your large table with the SMALLINT would be negligible in terms of performance and RAM use.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to specify the ids used in IPE_ALL_QUEUES, but there should be no benefit in them being SMALLINT rather than INT.

If you are storing a very large number of references to this table elsewhere, you could see a benefit from those references being of type SMALLINT (in terms of reduced storage requirement, particularly if the references are in a RAM-based object).

If so, you could add a layer of indirection which maps the SMALLINT (e.g. 14) to the required INT (e.g. 100004) - the indirection table would be replicated and tiny, and the cost of joining using it in addition to IPE_ALL_QUEUES and your large table with the SMALLINT would be negligible in terms of performance and RAM use.

```
CREATE TABLE largeref(qref SMALLINT, ...);
CREATE TABLE reflookup(qref SMALLINT, queue_id INT);
-- populate lookup with entries like (14, 100004)
-- populate largeref with SMALLINT references
-- replicate reflookup

SELECT Q.NAME, ...
FROM ipe_allqueues q, reflookup r, largeref l
WHERE q.id = r.queue_id
AND r.qref = l.qref
AND <other predicates on e.g. largeref>
```